# Generate random float number between [0,1], not fixed step but step must be larger than 0.05 in Python?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a list of random float number in range [0, 1] in Python. Something same to function `random.random_sample(size)` but I want to its step which is the size between each values larger than a number. For example all steps are randomly, not uniform but must be larger than 0.05. The result should be an array like this:

```
[0.07727264, 0.12850264, 0.19339824, 0.842385484, 0.17137362]
```

Is there any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Generate a random number between [0, 0.9], and if greater than `last_number-0.05` add 0.1. Of course, you'll need to handle values less than 0.05 and greater than 0.95, but that's how I'd start.

Comment: I'm not really get your idea. To make it more clear, in my example the array [0.07727264, 0.12850264, 0.19339824, 0.842385484, 0.17137362], has 4 steps between values, which are [0.05123, 0.0648956, .., ...] and all of them greater than 0.05. Is it matched with your idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it. With random numbers it is often easier and even faster to just generate a new one instead of modifying the wrong one.

```
def costum_random_sample(size):
    randomList = []
    counter = 0
    last_n = -1
    while(size != counter):
        n = random.random()
        if abs(n - last_n) < 0.05:
            continue
        else:
            randomList.append(n)
            counter += 1
            last_n = n

    return randomList
```

Comment: That's far more straightforward than my example, and unless the step value is something extreme like 0.99 we needn't worry about performance.

Comment: I worked a lot with random numbers in the past and the best generator we used had 5 ns per generated number. They can be crazy fast.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Anw, I got your idea @KenY-N

Comment: I will try both cuz I'm quite new to python